# Java: scanning string for a pattern

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is probably a quicky. Why does this code not return anything?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner("asda ASA adad");
        String pattern = "[A-Z]+";

        while ((sc.hasNext(pattern))) {

            System.out.println(sc.next(pattern));
        }
        sc.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`hasNext(String pattern)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.lang.String%29) only returns `true` if the next token matches the pattern. In your case, `"asda"` is the next token, and that does NOT match `"[A-Z]+"`. The documentation is clear in that "[the] scanner does not advance past any input".

If you change the pattern to `"[A-Za-z]+"`, then you'd get three tokens, which may be what you intended.

If in fact you only want to get tokens that match `"[A-Z]+"`, then you can do any of the following:

- simply discard non-matching tokens
- `useDelimiter("[^A-Z]+")`, then simply invoke `next()`
- use `skip("[^A-Z]+")`
- use `findInLine("[A-Z]+")`

Tip: if performance is critical, you'd want to use the precompiled `Pattern` overloads of these methods.

Tip: do keep in mind that`"Xooo ABC"` has two `"[A-Z]+"` matches. If this is not what you want, then the regex will have to be a bit more complicated. Or you can always simply discard non-matching tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String pattern = "[A-Z]+";
```

to

```
String pattern = "[a-zA-Z]+";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to print out all words surrounded by your delimiter you might want to be safe and exclude the pattern altogether.  That way you don't come across a word that contains a character not in your pattern which would cause your program exit that loop (as it's currently doing).  For example:

```
    while ((sc.hasNext())) {

        System.out.println(sc.next());
    }
```